# Get PrimaryStatus of DCIM_PhysicalDiskView and Put it in a variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am trying to use the primaryStatus from the DCIM_PhysicalDiskView and compare it to 3 (degraded hard disk). If there is a match, an email will be sent to notify the admin. Here is the code:

```
$computerNames = Get-Content -Path C:\scripts\nameTest.txt

foreach ($computer in $computerNames) {

write-host "$computer" 
$value = "3"
$smtpserver = "mailserver.xxxx.com" # your mail server here
$smtpFrom = "xx@xxxx.com" # your from address, mail server will most likely allow any
$smtpTo = "xx@xxxx.com" #your email address here. can also be an array and will send to all
$MessageSubject = "Testing Failed Disk in $computer" #whatever you want the subject to be. 


gwmi -Namespace root\dcim\sysman -computername $computer -Class DCIM_PhysicalDiskView | ForEach {$name = $_.Name; $primaryStatus = $_.PimaryStatus}
    if( $primaryStatus -contains $value )
    {
        Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtpserver -from $smtpFrom -to $smtpto -subject $messageSubject
        Write-Host "error message sent"
    }
}
```

My problem is that the command is not piping to the foreach. The $name and $primaryStatus are staying null, therefore not going through the if statement.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is `$_.PimaryStatus` a typo? The second ForEach does not look right either. You assign  `$primaryStatus` everytime so i will only remember the last entry.

Comment: @Matt it was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is your code with the braces changed for the foreach loop. Note that you will still need to have the closing brace from your opening `foreach-object`.

```
gwmi -Namespace root\dcim\sysman -computername $computer -Class DCIM_PhysicalDiskView | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.Name
    $primaryStatus = $_.PrimaryStatus
    if( $primaryStatus -eq $value )
    {
        Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtpserver -from $smtpFrom -to $smtpto -subject $messageSubject
        Write-Host "error message sent"
    }
}
```

Fixed the typo for `$_.PrimaryStatus` as well. Is `$primaryStatus` an array? `-Contains` only works with arrays. I think you wanted `-eq`? I dont have access to that namespace so i cannot test my theory. Also, I think that you could change this a little with a `Where-Object`.

```
gwmi -Namespace root\dcim\sysman -computername $computer -Class DCIM_PhysicalDiskView | 
    Where-Object { $primaryStatus -eq $value } | ForEach-Object{
        Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtpserver -from $smtpFrom -to $smtpto -subject $messageSubject
        Write-Host "error message sent"
    }
```

*disclaimer*: I do not have that namespace so I cannot test this but the logic looks sounds so it should work.

Comment: you are right. The suggested piece of code works like a champ! Thank you so much, you saved me a ton of headache.